# Como traduzir esse if javascript para o PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Como esse if em javascript ficaria em php?

```
        ...
        telefone = "11222223333"; // exemplo
        for (var n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
            if (telefone == new Array(11).join(n) || telefone == new Array(12).join(n)){
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Seria o in_array?

Comment: o que tem na variável "n"?

Comment: O que tem na variável `n` e a variável `$telefone` está como string ou array?

Comment: Depois das perguntas vi que seria melhor completar o codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percebe-se que a intenção é verificar se a variável `telefone` possui uma sequência com apenas o mesmo número. Neste caso, em PHP, pode-se usar a função **[array_unique](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-unique.php)** com `count`. Se o resultado for `1`, significa que a string possui a sequência repetitiva.

**Código:**

```
if( count(array_unique(str_split($telefone))) == 1 ){
    return false;
}
```

**[Teste no Ideone](https://ideone.com/0WhRbV)**

Comment: Hum... interessante e mais eficiente

Answer (score 3):

Em PHP, uma solução seria assim:

```
if ($telefone == str_repeat($n, 11) || $telefone == str_repeat($n, 12)){
     return false;
}
```

### Explicação

Esse teste que tem no código é meio estranho e acaba por dificultar a leitura, não dando ideia clara da sua intenção.

O que `new Array(11).join(n)` faz é criar um array de um determinado tamanho em que todas as casas tem `undefined`, e junta tudo com o separador passado. Mas os `undefineds` que estão em todas as casas são representados como texto vazio, logo vai ficar com uma `string` em que o separador foi repetido várias vezes.

Veja o seguinte exemplo:

```js
console.log(new Array(11).join('a'));
```

No entanto, melhor seria utilizar o [repeat da String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat), que é bem mais claro na sua intenção:

```js
console.log('a'.repeat(11));
```

Mesmo que o valor a repetir não seja uma `string` pode sempre transforma-lo em `string` e depois aplicar o `repeat`:

```js
let x = 3;
console.log(x.toString().repeat(11));
```

Em php tem a função [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) que faz precisamente o mesmo:

```
echo str_repeat('a', 11); //aaaaaaaaaa
```